# dhtmlxgrid table header do not move horizontally with column in mobile application

Tags: java, dhtmlx

My DHTMLXGrid table header do not move horizontally with column when I am using in mobile application but in case of desktop browser grid work fine. Can anyone suggest the correct solution?

```
mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
    mygrid.setImagePath("../dhtml/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/");
    mygrid.setHeader(thead_name_arr.join());        
    mygrid.setColumnIds(colID.join());      
    mygrid.setColAlign(rowColAlign.join());
    mygrid.setInitWidths(rowColWidth.join());
    mygrid.enableTooltips(toolTips.join());
    mygrid.setSkin("light");
    mygrid.enableColumnMove(true);
    mygrid.setEditable(false);
    mygrid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", doOnRowSelected);
    mygrid.init();
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the dragging of the columns/rows in dhtmlxGrid is not supported on touch devices.
You can move the columns using the API
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_movecolumn.html
Here you can find an example:
https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/16_rows_columns_manipulations/13_pro_grid_moveCol.html